# I have been trying to slice the image based on table rows and columns

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, data-science, ocr

How can i crop/slice each row out of the image?

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
from img2table.document import Image
from img2table.document import PDF

from IPython.display import display_html
from PIL import Image as PILImage
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from io import BytesIO

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



# Load image, convert to grayscale, and find edges
image = cv2.imread('NPT-0013-23-WEBSITE-ANNOUNCEMENT_V_2.png')
result = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]



# Find contour and sort by contour area
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

#======================================
# horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (40,1))
# detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
# cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
#    ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
#    break

    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 2)


cv2.imshow('RESULT',result)
# cv2.imwrite(f'ROI_{i}.png',ROI)
cv2.imwrite('RESULT.png',result)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[table to be scliced/cropped based on rows and columns:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6sP5.png)

Using the above code I get the following result
However I wish to crop the image based entire rows in the table.
Can somebody please help.
[Result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H93d7.png)

Comment: Use morphology with a horizontal kernel to connect the words in the rows as a mask.